# Why is my NextJS config file asking for types when I'm not using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, jestjs, config

I'm hoping someone can help me, I'm so confused. I just noticed there's an error showing up in my jsconfig.json file in a nextJS project:

the code looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The error in VSCode looks like this:

```
Cannot find type definition for 'testing-library__jest-dom' ts [line 1, col 1]
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'testing-library__jest-dom'
```

I am not using TypeScript in this project, so no idea why it's asking about types. Can someone help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Why do you have `compilerOptions` if you don't use TypeScript? Which compiler do you use?

Comment: when i install the nextJS npm package, it creates this file as-is -- I haven't changed anything